# Possible to dynamically change ng-model source?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel

Is it possible to 'unbind' an input to the scope variable when the input is not shown?

**EG:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value1" ng-show="true">
//The above input value would bind to $scope.value1


<input type="text" ng-model="value2" ng-show="false">
//The above input value would NOT bind to $scope.value2 as its hidden
```

Pheraps there is a way of having having an if statement within an ng-model

**EG:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="isBinded ? value : ''" ng-init="isBinded = true">
//The above input value is binds to $scope.value according to isBinded true or false
```

Comment: use ng-if instead of ng-hide and ng-show..

Answer (score 0):

You can create two input tags with different `ng-model` and use `ng-hide or ng-show` on those input tags.

Answer (score 0):

on web page:

```
<button ng-click="booleanValue1 = !booleanValue1">Toggle Show</button>

<input type="text" ng-model="value1show" ng-show="booleanValue1">
```

on controller:

```
$scope.value1 = "hello";

$scope.value1show = $scope.value1false = $scope.value1;

$scope.booleanValue1 = true;

$scope.$watch('booleanValue1', function () {
    if ($scope.booleanValue1) {
       $scope.value1 = $scope.value1show;
    } else {
       $scope.value1 = $scope.value1false;
    }
    console.log("value1 " + $scope.value1);
    console.log("value1show " + $scope.value1show);
    console.log("value1false " + $scope.value1false);
    console.log("");
});
```